# Can the Mask of Avacyn be targeted by spells after being equipped to a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can the [Mask of Avacyn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mask%20of%20Avacyn) be targeted by spells after it's been equipped to a creature?

This is an odd question, because the mask gives the equipped creature a +1/+2 and has hexproof  and says it "can't be the target of spells or abilities your opponent controls", where "it" refers to the equipped creature. However, can your opponent use a spell or ability to directly destroy the Mask of Avacyn (in this case an Artifact - Equipment card)?

Example: Mask of Avacyn is attached to a creature.  Can my opponent use the Planeswalker ability of Nicol Bolas that reads: "Destroy target noncreature permanent"?

Alternatively, can my opponent use a spell card that reads, "Destroy target permanent" or [Recoil](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Recoil), an Instant that reads:, "Return target permanent to its owner's hand. Then that player discards a card"?

Comment: the creature can't be the target of spells or abilities.  The mask itself still can.

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, please check the mark next to it. If not, please indicate why you think it isn't. Welcome to StackExchange!

Answer (score 13):

Yes. The Mask doesn't have *hexproof*, *shroud* or similar.

Even when attached, the equipment and the equipped creature are two separate permanents. Only the creature gets +1/+2 and hexproof. Nothing in the scenario you described gives the Mask any abilities (such as hexproof) when attached.

Comment: I would have thought that you could not attach the Mask directly unless you get rid of the creature first.  I would not have a problem it the equipment was on the battlefield and you wanted to destroy it with a destroy target card, however, I would think since in this case its attached to creature, that an opponent would have to destroy the creature first.  What do you think?

Comment: I already said what I think. Attaching the Mask doesn't give Mask hexproof or similar, so nothing's stopping you from targeting the Mask. It's the other way around, you can't target the creature until you get rid of the Mask first.

Comment: If you want Avacyn's Mask to have hexproof, you could try using Privileged Position (http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83720).  Note that Privileged Position can still be targeted by your opponent!